# How to use ISAAC in C

Tags: c, random, cryptography

I downloaded isaac64 from [here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html) and I have some problem with usage.
I had to comment a part of code in isaac64.c becouse it contained main function. But I can't use it... I can't properly initialize it and get random number, can you help me? I couldn'y found any example.

```
    randinit(TRUE); 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%lx\n",rand());
    }
```

each time I run this code I get the same values. I don't know how to set seed.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried and what errors you're getting?

Comment: Do you specifically want to use ISAAC or do you just want a [cryptographically secure random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Special_designs)? [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) is usually fine.

Comment: @Schwern i want to use ISAAC

Comment: @Bartek The code in main works for me. What have you tried?

Comment: @Schwern but you will ever get the same result and it's don't use rand() function.

Comment: @Bartek Isn't that the point of a random number generator, to not get the same result? And it's not going to use rand() because ISAAC is its own random number generator. Would you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: @Schwern i posted my code snippet. "Isn't that the point of a random number generator, to not get the same result?" - and this is the problem, that each time I get the same result. Each time i run macro rand() from isaac64.h i get the same values. i can't set seed.

Comment: @Bartek You're going to get the same numbers because you're always supplying the same seed. Psudo-random number generators require a random seed. See [this discussion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random::ISAAC#USAGE-WARNING) and consider whether you truly need to use ISAAC. It's not fully baked.

Comment: @Schwern so I have to add method initialising mm in siaac64.c ? Than you very much :)

Comment: @Bartek I was working from the 32 bit version. The 64 bit version looks basically the same but it's even less complete and uses global variables. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version of ISAAC is a "reference implementation" meaning it's intended to be referred to but isn't particularly user friendly or ready for production. There are any number of [cryptographically secure random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Special_designs) in C that are easier to use. In particular, simply reading bytes from [/dev/random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) is good enough on most operating systems.

---

The `main` function demonstrates how to use the library. It's already commented out with `#ifdef`s.  I've found [using the Perl wrapper around ISAAC as a guide](https://metacpan.org/source/JAWNSY/Math-Random-ISAAC-XS-1.004/src/ISAAC.xs) also helps.

```
int main()
{
    /* Initialize the structure to 0 */
    randctx ctx;
    ctx.randa = ctx.randb = ctx.randc = (ub4)0;

    /* Initialize the seed */
    for (ub4 i=0; i<256; ++i) {
        ctx.randrsl[i] = i;
    }

    /* Initialize the random numbers from the seed */
    randinit(&ctx, TRUE);

    /* Print 10 pseudo random numbers */
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%.8lx\n", rand(&ctx));
    }
}
```

**You must supply the `seed`**, or ["entropy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29). If you supply the same seed you will get the same result. This is why ISAAC is a *psuedo* random number generator, it can only make more random-seeming numbers out of existing randomness. There is [a discussion of where to get your seed from in Math::Random::ISAAC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Random::ISAAC#USAGE-WARNING).

If these are new concepts to you, and if this for production code, I would **strongly recommend you simply read from `/dev/random`**. This ISAAC implementation is very rough and cryptography is *very easy* to get wrong. `/dev/random` has already taken care of all of this for you.

If you must use your own pseudo-random library, use a well-implemented and documented library like [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/rand.html).

If you're going to go through with this, I would recommend adapting [the version of the code from the Perl wrapper](https://metacpan.org/source/JAWNSY/Math-Random-ISAAC-XS-1.004/src) because at least the author has cleaned it up to be release worthy.