# How to supply seed to ISAAC random number generator

Tags: c, random, cryptography

I have the following code to generate a random number using ISAAC:

```
int main()
{
    /* Initialize the structure to 0 */
    randctx ctx;
    ctx.randa = ctx.randb = ctx.randc = (ub4)0;

    /* Initialize the seed */
    for (ub4 i=0; i<256; ++i) {
        ctx.randrsl[i] = i;
    }

    /* Initialize the random numbers from the seed */
    randinit(&ctx, TRUE);

    printf("%.8lx\n", rand(&ctx));
}
```

I got the above code from [How to use ISAAC in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402981/how-to-use-isaac-in-c)

I also have a code to read from /dev/random to get the seed:

```
int myFile = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);            
uint32_t rand;            
uint32_t randomNum = read(myFile, &rand, sizeof(rand)) ;
printf(" %u \n", rand);
close(myFile);
```

How do I supply the seed i.e rand to ISAAC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing `TRUE` to flags of `randinit` the seed is taken from `ctx.randrsl`. But I'd recommend using the `RANDSIZ` or `sizeof(ctx.randrsl)` instead of hardcoding its value of 256.

So:

```
ssize_t bytes_read = read(myFile, &ctx.randrsl, sizeof(ctx.randrsl));
if(bytes_read != sizeof(ctx.randrsl)){ printf("cannot initialize seed\n"); exit(1); }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I always get cannot initialize seed. It seems that the probability of bytes_read to be equal to the sizeof(ctx.randrsl) is extremely low. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @user3266083 it simply reads bytes from file, this should only fail on unusual cases. Is `myFile` opened successfully (should be >= 0)?

Comment: Yes file is opened successfully. And just FYI I'm running this on a Linux VM.

Comment: @user3266083 your machine may not have enough entropy and not have a hardware random generator. Try with `/dev/urandom` (this fall back to pseudo-random and does not wait for noise gathering)

Comment: Yep urandom worked. I guess the VM can't create enough entropy. Thanks a lot for your help! :)